# How to find the AVG given some instructions SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a query that returns me the Market.name and the average of the employees who worked for a particular Market, for example the average of the employees who worked for "IKEA" is 10% compared to all of the total employees among all of the markets.

[image: This is a part of the database schema]

Comment: Hint:  Such a query starts with `SELECT` and will use `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried with a subquery but I did not succeed so I'm looking for other ways, I assume there are simpler, but right now I can not find one

Comment: Do you want average or number of employees worked in the market.

Comment: I have to find the average of the employees who worked for a particular market, for example the average of the employees who worked for "IKEA" is 10% compared to all the high market

Comment: maybe I did not explain well, the question is: For each Market, find the percentage of participating employee that worked for "IKEA'. Return the mission name and the corresponding percentage

Answer (score 0):

You need such a SQL statement with joins

```
   select m.name market_name,
           100*round(count(w.employee_id)::decimal/
                (select count(employee_id) from employee ),2)
            as "Avg Percent of Emp. Per Market"
      from workson w
      left join market m on ( m.market_id = w.market_id )
    where m.name = 'IKEA' 
    group by m.name;
```

*I don't know about your DBMS, I tried if it is Postgres, remove **::decimal** if MySQL*

[***Rextester Demo 1***](https://rextester.com/GSOKG78179)

[***Rextester Demo 2***](https://rextester.com/ILQR17747)

Comment: This query returns the name of the market and how many employees it has, not the average of the employees who worked for a given market

Comment: but where is the condition that the employee works for the market "IKEA"

Comment: @Gabrielenones ok, I've just added " where m.name = 'IKEA' "

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select m.name as "Market Name",
   avg(w.employee_id) as "Avg.NumberofEmployeesPerMarket"
from workson w
left join employee e on ( e.employee_id = w.employee_id )
left join market m on ( m.market_id = w.market_id )
group by m.name;
```

Comment: maybe I did not explain well, the question is: For each Market, find the percentage of participating employee that worked for "IKEA'.
Return the mission name and the corresponding percentage.